# How do I create a single page application in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, single-page-application

I'm creating my first Rails 3.2 application after completing the excellent [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/).

I would like my application to do this:

Pull a random recipe from the database (I have finished this bit using the 'index' action and this bit of code: `@recipe = Recipe.find(:first, :order => 'Random()'))`

If the user clicks the 'something similar' button, the app fetches a related recipe from the db

If the user clicks 'something different', the app fetches an unrelated recipe

From what I understand, there should be an action for both 'something similar' and 'something different'. Is this correct?

Should I use a  POST form with submit buttons for 'something different' and 'something similar' to determine which action to take?

Also, how can I keep the user on a single page throughout (so they always see the URL as http://www.whatshouldicookfordinner.co.uk rather than /recipes#somethingdifferent)?

Answer (score 0):

To keep the user on the same page throughout, you will want to use AJAX.  Check out this [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax), you can apply the concept to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use a javascript framework/library (Ember, Backbone, Angular, Knockout, Meteor, Batman, etc..)

Check out this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/323-backbone-on-rails-part-1